# What is the subject of this participle in this context?

Tags: subjects, participles

What is the subject of paving? 'Adidas?' or 'a landmark deal with Adidas?' I thought 'a landmark deal with Adidas', however, one of my friends told that 'Adidas' is the subject. I want to know how to explain this grammatically.

> In the mid-80s, hip-hop group Run-DMC signed a landmark deal with Adidas **paving** the way for many more lucrative partnerships between shoe makers and artists.

[Here is the web reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNjJthwOVOc)

Comment: It was the fact that "hip-hop group Run-DMC signed a landmark deal" that paved the way for more lucrative partnerships. So Adidas is not the subject. It didn't do the paving; the landmark deal did. :-)

Comment: IF there was a comma after ***...a landmark deal*** then Adidas would indeed be the subject of the verb ***paving***. The net meaning wouldn't really be changed, though - just the syntactic constructions.

Comment: "Paving the way for ..." is a supplementary result adjunct, and as such is not a modifier but a supplement. Its 'anchor' is the whole of the clause that precedes it. A comma after "Adidas" would be helpful.

Comment: A way to see @BillJ’s point is to consider that if we split the sentence in two just before *paving*, then the new sentence could start with “This paved…” or “This deal paved…” or “This event, paved…,” but not with “They paved…”